# Append arbitrary jar to classpath using Java Service Wrapper from the command line?

Tags: java, java-service-wrapper

I want to run my application using Java Service Wrapper and append something to the classpath from the command line.

So I have the command line:

```
wrapper.exe -c app.conf \
    wrapper.ignore_sequence_gaps=TRUE \
    wrapper.java.classpath.200=path/to/extra/jar \
    wrapper.debug=TRUE
```

But the extra jar is not in the classpath passed to my application.

Comment: Are there spaces in the path and if so should you enclose the path in quotes?

Comment: There are no spaces in the path to the extra jar.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

what version of the Wrapper are you using?

The older versions of the Wrapper required that the classpath elements had to be strictly ordered. any gap in the ordering caused the Wrapper to stop at that certain point.
In the command line you posted the classpath element is 200, which means you would have to have 199 declarations in your conf file in order to make this work....

To make things more easy, you should run at least 3.3.6 for this since that version the [wrapper.ignore_sequence_gaps](http://wrapper.tanukisoftware.com/doc/english/prop-ignore-sequence-gaps.html) property was added.

Set the following property either in the command line or the conf file to TRUE. and it should work.

Edit: Sorry, I just noticed you are already setting wrapper.ignore_sequence_gaps to TRUE in the command line... So probably you are running an earlier version of the wrapper.

Best regards,